# React JSX for loop shows only the last value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen similar questions here, but these haven't been helpful so far.

I have a component that has an array state:

```
eventData: []
```

Some logic watches for events and pushes the objects to the state array:

```
eventData.unshift(result.args);

this.setState({ eventData });;
```

`unshift()` here is used to push the new elements to the top of the array.

What I want to achieve is rendering the content of the state array. I have written a conditional that checks for a certain state, and based on that state decides what to output.

```
let allRecords;

if (this.state.allRecords) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.eventData.length; i++) {
    (i => {
      allRecords = (
        <div className="event-result-table-container">
          <div className="result-cell">
            {this.state.eventData[i].paramOne}
          </div>
          <div className="result-cell">
            {() => {
              if (this.state.eventData[i].paramTwo) {
                <span>Win</span>;
              } else {
                <span>Loose</span>;
              }
            }}
          </div>
          <div className="result-cell">
            {this.state.eventData[i].paramThree.c[0]}
          </div>
          <div className="result-cell">
            {this.state.eventData[i].paramFour.c[0]}
          </div>
          <div className="result-cell">
            {this.state.eventData[i].paramFive.c[0] / 10000}
          </div>
          <div className="result-cell-last">
            {this.state.eventData[i].paramSix.c[0]}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }).call(this, i);
  }
} else if (!this.state.allRecords) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.eventData.length; i++) {
    if (this.state.account === this.state.eventData[i].paramOne) {
      (i => {
        allRecords = (
          <div className="event-result-table-container">
            <div className="result-cell">
              {this.state.eventData[i].paramOne}
            </div>
            <div className="result-cell">
              {() => {
                if (this.state.eventData[i].paramTwo) {
                  <span>Win</span>;
                } else {
                  <span>Loose</span>;
                }
              }}
            </div>
            <div className="result-cell">
              {this.state.eventData[i].paramThree.c[0]}
            </div>
            <div className="result-cell">
              {this.state.eventData[i].paramFour.c[0]}
            </div>
            <div className="result-cell">
              {this.state.eventData[i].paramFive.c[0] / 10000}
            </div>
            <div className="result-cell-last">
              {this.state.eventData[i].paramSix.c[0]}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }).call(this, i);
    }
  }
}
```

Problems that I have with this piece of code:

1. The code always renders the very last value of `eventData` state object.
2. I would like to limit the rendered elements to always show not more than 20 objects (the last 20 records of the state array).
3. **paramTwo** is a bool, and according to its value I expect to see either **Win** or **Loose**, but the field is empty (I get the `bool` value via the `console.log`, so I know the value is there)

Is this even the most effective way of achieving the needed? I was also thinking of mapping through the elements, but decided to stick with a for loop instead.

I would appreciate your help with this.

Comment: First off, NEVER modify state directly. `this.state.eventData.unshift(result);` is really bad, you need to modify state in [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and only in `setState`. Next: map and for-loop do the same thing basically, though with the for-loop you don't need to do all the binding stuff because there is no new function scope created as there would be in a `.map` callback.

Comment: Apologies for the unshift(), I am using setState. That part I wrote here manually, so there was a mistake I edited now.

Comment: @coreyward I am new to React, and some parts are not still quite clear to me yet. I would be thankful if you could point me to those issues.

Comment: This not the most effective way, without seeing the whole context of the code it's hard to say exactly what's going on. One thing to note, your outer most if and else if contain almost identical blocks of code, so you should rewrite that. It should be a map yes, then showing the last 20 objects is just a matter of slicing this array. The reason you don't see Win or Loose (which is probably a typo btw, should be Lose) is because your function is never invoked, it should be {() => { ... }()}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things :

First, as the comments above already pointed out, changing state without using `setState` goes against the way React works, the simplest solution to fix this would be to do the following :

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ 
    eventData: [...prevState.eventData, result.args]
}));
```

The problem with your code here. Is that the arrow function was never called :

```
{() => {
        if (this.state.eventData[i].paramTwo) {
            <span>Win</span>;
        } else {
            <span>Loose</span>;
        }
    }
}
```

This function can be reduced to the following (after applying the deconstructing seen in the below code) :

```
<span>{paramTwo ? 'Win' : 'Lose'}</span>
```

Next up, removing repetitions in your function by mapping it. By setting conditions at the right place and using ternaries, you can reduce your code to the following and directly include it the the JSX part of your render function :

```
render(){
    return(
        <div> //Could also be a fragment or anything
            {this.state.allRecords || this.state.account === this.state.eventData[i].paramOne && 
                this.state.eventData.map(({ paramOne, paramTwo, paramThree, paramFour, paramFive, paramSix }, i) =>
                    <div className="event-result-table-container" key={i}> //Don't forget the key like I just did before editing
                        <div className="result-cell">
                            {paramOne}
                        </div>
                        <div className="result-cell">
                            <span>{paramTwo ? 'Win' : 'Lose'}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="result-cell">
                            {paramThree.c[0]}
                        </div>
                        <div className="result-cell">
                            {paramFour.c[0]}
                        </div>
                        <div className="result-cell">
                            {paramFive.c[0] / 10000}
                        </div>
                        <div className="result-cell-last">
                            {paramSix.c[0]}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Finally, to only get the 20 first elements of your array, use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) :

```
this.state.eventData.slice(0, 20).map(/*  CODE ABOVE */)
```

---

EDIT :

Sorry, I made a mistake when understanding the condition you used in your rendering, here is the fixed version of the beginning of the code :

```
{this.state.allRecords && 
    this.state.eventData.filter(data => this.state.account === data.paramOne).slice(0, 20).map(/* CODE ABOVE */)
```

Here, we are using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to only use your array elements respecting a given condition.

---

EDIT 2 :

I just made another mistake, hopefully the last one. This should ahve the correct logic :

```
this.state.eventData.filter(data => this.state.allRecords || this.state.account === data.paramOne).slice(0, 20).map(/* CODE ABOVE */)
```

If `this.state.allRecords` is defined, it takes everything, and if not, it checks your condition.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm trying to incorporate this to my now.

Comment: Could you please edit your code by adding the code within the .map function? For some reason I'm getting typo errors, and having a hard time to stick things together.

Comment: You simply have to put the `.slice(0, 20)` up between `this.state.eventData` and `.map`

Comment: Gotcha! Now, I'm getting an error that [i] is not defined.

Comment: I have added the keys, but still getting the undefined [i] error at this line: this.state.eventData[i].paramOne

Comment: Thanks! but are you sure the logic is correct now? I have added the code, and the app renders, but I don't get the data to show up. The logic is either I show first 20 any records of the state, or I show the first 20 where paramOne matches to the this.state.account.

Comment: Wow, I really shouldn't code so late, just edited it again

Comment: I'm afraid there's still something's missing, as I have a switcher that sets allRecords on and off, and when the switcher is on and allRecords is true, I can see all the records, but when I set the switch to off, I can't see the filtered result according to the condition :(

Comment: Weird, the code seems to be doing the exact same condition as your code right now, could you trying printing out `this.state.account` and the `this.state.eventData` in your console to see what's going wrong ?

Comment: I'll try debugging to see what's wrong. Enormous thanks to you, man. I will accept the answer now, as the rest is debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up and refactored your code a bit. I wrote a common function for the repetitive logic and passing the looped object to the common function to render it.

Use Map instead of forloops. You really need to check this `this.state.account === this.state.eventObj.paramOne` statement. This could be the reason why you see only one item on screen.

Please share some dummy data and the logic behind `unshift` part(never do it directly on state object), we'll fix it.

```
getRecord = (eventObj) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div className="result-cell">
      {eventObj.paramOne}
    </div>
    <div className="result-cell">
      {eventObj.paramTwo ? <span>Win</span> : <span>Loose</span>}
    </div>
    <div className="result-cell">
      {eventObj.paramThree.c[0]}
    </div>
    <div className="result-cell">
      {eventObj.paramFour.c[0]}
    </div>
    <div className="result-cell">
      {eventObj.paramFive.c[0] / 10000}
    </div>
    <div className="result-cell-last">
      {eventObj.paramSix.c[0]}
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
)


render() {
  let allRecords;

  if (this.state.allRecords) {
    allRecords = <div>{this.state.eventData.map(eventObj => this.getRecord(eventObj)}</div>;
  } else if (!this.state.allRecords) {
    allRecords = <div>{this.state.eventData.map(eventObj => {
      if (this.state.account === this.state.eventObj.paramOne) {
        return this.getRecord(eventObj);
      }
      return null;
    })}</div>;
  }
  return (<div className="event-result-table-container">{allRecords}</div>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have incorporated your answer to the code but got an error  "React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in." As for the data, the event returns an object, which I assign to a variable, and then setState it to the state array.